# How do I output a certain array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

Objective C language-->

I have cvs file, i want to read it into a NSString and create arrays i.e.:

Name, State, Price, Zipcode

John, WI, 20000, 43555
..
..

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <string.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

{
@autoreleasepool {
    //input user for a name on property list    
    int input;
NSLog(@"The worldcities.cvs contained infor on property names.");       
        NSLog(@"Enter a name: ");       
        scanf("%i", &input);

NSString *sourceFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"worldcities.csv"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

        NSMutableArray *csvArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        csvArray = [[sourceFileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];

        NSString *keysString = [csvArray objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *keysArray = [keysString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        [csvArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

I want to to be able to output a property name based on user input from the create array from the .cvs file, how would i proceed?

Comment: Please explain your problem??What output you needed?

Comment: How do i ouput my array stored in cvsArray based on user input?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than store it in an array, you could create a core data structure and populate that with your information from your .csv file. Then, based on user input, you could use an NSPredicate to query for whatever you need to output.

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) is a really nice tutorial on using Core Data and also populating Core Data using a pre-existing file.

Comment: that is past my league, i just need to store in NSArray and output the result base on user input.